# If JWT payload modified/manipulated is it still verified by jsonwebtoken module?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

The title says everything. 
If someone changes the payload but doesn't change the encrypted part, is it verified by the module?

Comment: If it works after alteration then what is the point of using it?

Comment: No, the signature is a hash of header and payload, if you change anything ithe sig is invalid

Comment: That's precisely what you use the signature part to do; validate that the token hasn't been altered.